# Не загружается пользовательский Firefox профиль. Selenium WebDriver + C#

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium, profile

```
FirefoxProfileManager manage = new FirefoxProfileManager();
FirefoxProfile profile = manage.GetProfile("myprofile");
IWebDriver browser = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Есть код, который пытается открыть браузер Firefox с пользовательским профилем. Этот код слизан с туториала Selenium. Но вместо открытия происходит следующая ошибка:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу
>   "C:\Users\Владимир\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\1h0nvz5l.default\parent.lock",
>   так как этот файл используется другим процессом.

Дефолтный профиль `IWebDriver browser = new FirefoxDriver();` открывает без проблем. Ошибка возникает по той причине, что окно Firefox уже открыто, но если совсем все закрыть, то около минуты ничего не происходит, после чего выскакивает другая ошибка. В общем суть не в ошибке, а в том, какой на данный момент рабочий код позволит загружать пользовательский профиль. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, текст ошибки, когда запускаете код с закрытым Firefox.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: А другие драйверы пробовали запускать "с нуля"?

Comment: C нуля работает абсолютно все! И опера, и хром, и мозилла. Только с пользовательскими профилями проблема.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно использовать класс FirefoxOptions и его свойство BrowserExecutableLocation.

```
FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
        firefoxOptions.BrowserExecutableLocation = "path to profile";
        var driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
```